# Building project form multiple subprojects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, guice

I have one project that I have modularized using Google Guice. But now when I build subproject I have many steps:

```
1) Update subproject version number.
2) Pacakage subproject. 
3) Update local repository with subproject new version.
4) Update main project pom.xml with subproject newest version number.
5) Update main project dependencies.
6) Run main project as web appliaction, to test changes in subproject.
```

Is it possible to cut down some of these steps to make my development faster? I'm using local repository and installing subproject jars manually to local repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin, it should help a lot in your situation.

Comment: Are you using it properly? I remember I had problems in the past, due to creating projects **one after the other** from m2eclipse. IIRC, you need to create the root project and then all depending projects will come along as dependencies in eclipse.

Comment: How can I create root project ?

Comment: By root project, I first mean "maven root project", this can be multi-module or just a normal project that refers to other maven subprojects (I think they must be in the same directory tree). Then import the root project and all its dependencies, **at the same time** with m2eclipse.